# MySQL doesn't generate expected/correct values

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I've never had this problem before at all, but this morning, I decided to make a new program that would generate the values from rows and synchronize them with the controls in the program. I've come across a bit-mask value (1, 2, 4, 8, 16) etc. but the MySQL doesn't give me its certain values.

When I go to ID 116, the value is 15 (8 + 4 + 2 + 1), it has to check 4 CheckBoxes, but it only checks the first one (1). After I navigate to ID 116 for the second time, it's correct, but not on the first time. What seems to be the problem? Here's a little bit of the code:

```
cmd.Connection = connection;
connection.Close();
connection.Open();
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    byte mask = (byte)reader.GetValue(3);
    UInt32 flagg = 1;

    for (int f = 0; f < maskBoxes.Count; ++f)
    {
         maskBoxes[f].IsChecked = ((mask & flagg) != 0) ? true : false;

         flagg = flagg + flagg;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to handle the connections?

Comment: Nope... it's the same thing. :(

Also, see the code above again. Edited.

Comment: Are you sure CheckBoxes are not changed from other place? P.S. you can replace `((mask & flagg) != 0) ? true : false` with `(mask & flagg) != 0`

Comment: Okay, so I did: flag = Math.Pow(2, f); and it worked, but it's the same problem, now with the value of 15. :(

Comment: And yes, I'm PRETTY sure that they're not changed from other places. It's just this one. :(

Comment: Why is `flagg` variable type `UInt32`? Did you debug it?

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm using HeidiSQL and the row is defined as INT (Unsigned).

Comment: It's just so strange that this thing has worked a million times before (at least for me), but now, it doesn't? When I select an ID for the first time, it just doesn't work, but the second time, it's flawless...

Comment: I think I fixed it. But in a strange way... I called the function "Update" to update it (twice I don't know why) and it worked on almost every value. Strange. ;S